# How to console.log from ChromeWorker (alternative to dump)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

How to use "Browser Console" from Worker?

Edit:
I hate the dum pconsole:

I just started using `ChromeWorker`s and couldn't use the awesome `console.log`. But the console window is soooo bad, things are cut off, you cant scroll etc etc. Is there any alternative to `dump` from `ChromeWorker`? I know of `throw` but that interrupts the code.

Picture of the `firefox.exe -console` (the dump console) im talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatives to `dump()` or `throw()` in a Worker (Your question is not clear as to you wanting a different *method* to use for output to the System Console, or if you are wanting alternatives to using the System Console as the display for text output from a Worker):

1. If you are desiring to use the System Console (i.e. "Native Console", "Dump Console"), there does not appear to be an alternative to `dump()` and `throw()` from JavaScript, or at least I did not find one in searching the docs and trying a variety of things. You can, however, control the properties of the system console to alleviate some of the issues you mentioned in your question. How to do so depends on your OS (see below).
2. The MDN docs indicate that you can redirect the output which is directed to the System Console with the `-console` option to a file by redirecting stderr. Effectively, this implies that you should be able to redirect that output to whatever you desire.  This would include any display/paging/console like application/process you desire. Obviously, how to do this and what alternatives are available depend on your OS. There are *many* different options and possibilities.
3. Using the JavaScript Console from a Worker: The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope) indicate that the ["normal" console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) (e.g. [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console), JavaScript Console, etc.) is available to Workers through the WorkerGlobalScope property. Thus, the normal console is accessed through `WorkerGlobalScope.console`, or perhaps `self.console` or a GlobalScope specialized by worker type. So, the normal `console.log()` should be `self.console.log()`. As of Firefox 32.0.1 `self.console.log` and multiple other `self.console.*` methods are defined as functions in the worker's context, but produce no output in any of the consoles.  Thus, we have to fake it (see Polyfill).

Re: Your issues with the System Console:
[Pulling info from our comments to my previous answer into this one to consolidate what should actually be relevant into one answer]:

The console to which you are referring in your question is the "System Console", also referred to as the "Native Console". The characteristics of this console will depend on the operating system on which you are running Firefox. Thus, we need to know what OS you are using.

On Windows (you previously asked a Windows based FF question elsewhere, so the info may be helpful): The properties of the window are accessed through the menu opened by right-clicking on the window title-bar -->properties. You then want the "Layout" tab. You probably also want to change the font under the "Font" tab. You can change the width and height of the window that is displayed as well as the width and height of the buffer. Changing the size of the buffer allows you to have a larger, scrollable area that is not cropped. You can then assign the changes to the shortcut that started the window and have your changes come up the next time your start Firefox (at least it does if you have created a shortcut to access a particular profile and added the -console to it).  This was tested with a shortcut that contained the following in the "Target" field: `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -purgecaches -no-remote -P "<your profile name here>"`.

---

### Polyfill:

There were a significant number of methods described in the [MDN Console documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) which do not actually exist in any context in which I tried them. These are commented out from the polyfill. The polyfill does not attempt to make either the source file or the line number displayed in the console be correct. It would be possible to make at least the errors and warnings show the correct file, but that already happens correctly for actual errors and warnings (i.e. not the ones written into the code).

This polyfill relies on hijacking very specific messages posted back to the calling process. If the passed message is an object with `{type : "Console message", subType : <one of the console types>}` then it is assumed to be a message that is to be forwarded to the console via the method specified in the subType.

The following code has been tested in the worker code you provided.

There are two alternates for the code in bootstrap.js. Alternate 1 should be used if you are really only going to use the uncomplicated printing of incoming messages. Alternate #2: If you were already doing complex processing of messages, it might be conceptually easier to make the console message handling a wrapper function.

Code added to your **myWorker.js**:

```
var console = {
    log : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "log",            message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    error : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "error",          message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    /* Not an actual function.
    _exception : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "_exception",     message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    */
    info : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "info",           message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    warn : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "warn",           message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    /* Not a standard function, and did not want to deal with an arbitrary number of parameters. 
    assert : function (msg,stat) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "assert",         message : msg, status : stat};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    */
    /* Not an actual function.
    count : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "count",          message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    */
    debug : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "debug",          message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    dir : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "dir",            message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    group : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "group",          message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    /* Not an actual function.
    groupCollapsed : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "groupCollapsed", message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    */
    groupEnd : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "groupEnd",       message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    /* Not actual functions. Probably would not have worked correctly anyway.
    profile : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "profile",        message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    profileEnd : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "profileEnd",     message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    */
    /* Not an actual function.
    table : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "table",          message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    */
    time : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "time",           message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    timeEnd : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "timeEnd",        message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
    trace : function (msg) {
        var toSend = { type : "Console message", subType : "trace",          message : msg};
        postMessage(toSend);
    },
}
```

Alternate #1: Code added (with a small amount of context) in your **bootstrap.js** (just insert handling console messages inline):

```
function handleMessageFromWorker(msg) {
    if (   typeof msg.data == "object"
        && typeof msg.data.type == "string"
        && typeof msg.data.subType == "string"
        && msg.data.type == "Console message"
        && typeof console[msg.data.subType] == "function"
    ){
        if(msg.data.subType == "trace") {
            //This will not work as desired.
            //Obviously doing a trace here will output a trace of this function, not the worker.
            console.error("WORKER STACK TRACE REQUESTED: This is NON-FUNCTIONAL.");
            return;
        } //else
        console[msg.data.subType](msg.data.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log('incoming message from worker, msg:', msg);
}

myWorker.addEventListener('message', handleMessageFromWorker);
```

Alternate #2: Code added/changed (with a small amount of context) in your **bootstrap.js** (wrap the message handler with a function that handles the console messages, keeps this conceptually a bit more separate):

```
function wrapHandleMessageFromWorker(msg) {
    if (   typeof msg.data == "object"
        && typeof msg.data.type == "string"
        && typeof msg.data.subType == "string"
        && msg.data.type == "Console message"
        && typeof console[msg.data.subType] == "function"
    ){
        if(msg.data.subType == "trace") {
            //This will not work as desired.
            //Obviously doing a trace here will output a trace of this function, not the worker.
            console.error("WORKER STACK TRACE REQUESTED: This is NON-FUNCTIONAL.");
            return;
        } //else
        console[msg.data.subType](msg.data.message);
        return;
    }
    handleMessageFromWorker(msg);
}

function handleMessageFromWorker(msg) {
    console.log('incoming message from worker, msg:', msg);
}

myWorker.addEventListener('message', wrapHandleMessageFromWorker);
```

**Test code** added to **myWorker.js**:

```
function sendOutput(){ 
    dump("\n\n\nSending console output....");
    //self.console.profile();
    self.console.time("timeTest");
    self.console.log("This is a worker test message.");
    self.console.error("This is a worker error message.");
    self.console.info("This is a worker info message.");
    self.console.warn("This is a worker warning message.");
    self.console.timeEnd("timeTest");
    self.console.trace();
    //self.console.profileEnd();
    self.console.group();
    self.console.log("This is a worker grouped message 1.");
    self.console.log("This is a worker grouped message 2.");
    self.console.groupEnd();
    //self.console.groupCollapsed();
    //self.console.log("This is a worker collapsed group message 1.");
    //self.console.log("This is a worker collapsed group message 2.");
    //self.console.groupEnd();
    //self.console.table({first:"first name",last:"last name"});
    self.console.dir({first:"first name",last:"last name"});
    //self.console.count("first name");
    //self.console.count("first name");
    //self.console.count("first name");
    //self.console.count("first name");
    //self.console.assert(false, "test assert false");
    //self.console.assert(true, "test assert true");
    self.console.debug("This is a worker debug message.");
    //self.console._exception("This is a worker _exception message.");
    dump("Sent console output.\n\n\n");
}

var timeoutID = setTimeout(sendOutput, 10000); //I wanted this well after all Firefox initialization so it was easier to see the output.
```

Comment: Thanks man for such a super post! Point __3__ was what I was looking for. I was trying to use the "Browser Console" from workers. I didn't test it out but will do right now. Thanks!!

Comment: Aw dang, neither `WorkerGlobalScope.console.log('rawr')` nor  `self.console.log('rawr')` worked. :( any ideas? :( Here is a super basic ChromeWorker thing I use to test stuff: [GitHub :: Noitidart / ChromeWorker](https://github.com/Noitidart/ChromeWorker/)

Comment: Ooo I see what you did there!! Thank you so much. I really appreciate it cuz you did so much work after I accepted the solution! Thanks man it works superb!!

Comment: Gosh this is so good, it helps me everyday, thanks for this awesome answer Makyen.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer provides information regarding sending output the the Browser/Web/JavaScript console, which was not quite what was desired by the original question.]

Yes, the console window has some very significant drawbacks. For me, the one that is most significant is that it is very, very slow when displaying a significant amount of information.

I am not sure what your issue is regarding lack of scrolling. One possibility is that you are saying that it is not displaying that many lines.  You can adjust the number of lines that are displayed in the console by changing the following preferences:

- devtools.hud.loglimit.exception
- devtools.hud.loglimit.console
- devtools.hud.loglimit.cssparser
- devtools.hud.loglimit.network

Change these to the number of lines you desire to display.

As to things being cut off, the only thing along this line which I have experienced is that long, single-call output is initially displayed truncated. However, there has always been a control (located in-line with the output) to expand such output to its full length. If I recall correctly, this is an ellipse "..." at the end of the line. Click on it and it expands to all the text that was output in that call.

I am not sure if it will work in a Chromeworker as I do not have one coded at the moment.   Thus, you will need to test in your environment. However, what I have found to work when there is no `window` available (e.g. during the bootstrap process) is:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");       //Services
/*
 * Send a string to the Browser/Web console marked as a warning.
 */
function consoleWarningMessage(text) {
    var warningMessage = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scripterror;1"]
                                 .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptError);
    warningMessage.init(text,null,null,null,null,1,null);
    Services.console.logMessage(warningMessage);
}

/*
 * Send a string to the Browser/Web console marked as an exception.
 */
function consoleExceptionMessage(text) {
    var exceptionMessage = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scripterror;1"]
                                 .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptError);
    exceptionMessage.init(text,null,null,null,null,2,null);
    Services.console.logMessage(exceptionMessage);
}

/*
 * Send a string to the Browser/Web console marked as a strict error.
 */
function consoleStrictMessage(text) {
    var strictMessage = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scripterror;1"]
                                 .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptError);
    strictMessage.init(text,null,null,null,null,4,null);
    Services.console.logMessage(strictMessage);
}

/*
 * Send a string message to the Browser/Web console.
 */
function consoleMessage(text) {
    Services.console.logStringMessage(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a long post. The issue though is not the browser console but the dump console. If you open firefox with command line of -console you get a black window. Pic here: ![](http://i.imgur.com/YyQgv1G.png)

Comment: Ahh... thank you. That is more specific, and not what I assumed.  Firefox natively has at least 4 different consoles: a "System Console", "Web Console", "Browser Console", and "Error Console" it helps to know exactly to which you are referring.

Comment: Given that you are using the "System Console", we need to know what operating system you are using. Some of your issues should be resolvable in some operating systems. For example, under Windows, You can change the width and height of the window that is displayed as well as the width and height of the buffer.  Changing the size of the buffer allows you to have a larger, scrollable area that is not cropped. You can then assign the changes to the shortcut that started the window and have your changes come up the next time your start. Other operating systems will have different capabilities.

Comment: The "System Console" also appears to be called the "Native Console" in some MDN docs.  On Windows the properties are selected by a right-click on the window title-bar -->properties.  You then want the "Layout" tab. You probably also want to change the font under the "Font" tab.

Comment: It appears that WorkerGlobalScope.console should give you access to the "Web Console" (i.e. the normal console interface).  MDN also says: "This interface is usually specialized by each worker type: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope for dedicated workers, SharedWorkerGlobalScope for shared workers, and ServiceWorkerGlobalScope. The self property returns the specialized scope for each context."  See it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope).

Comment: I edited topic question, clarifying i want to use Browser Console. Thanks man so much for your attempts to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean from inside an addon, to use console.log, this is what I use:

```
// import the module, usually on top of the page
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm');

// afterwards  you can use console.log normally
console.log('whatever');
```

Comment: From inside ChromeWorker please :)

Comment: @Noitidart Does this help? [Web workers: errors and debugging](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/08/25/web-workers-errors-and-debugging/) or [Chrome Worker Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/ChromeWorkers/Chrome_Worker_Modules)